# Fetching data from a List

Tags: pyspark

I am new to PySpark and have purchased a book to enhance my PySpark skills. I am stuck while using a function.

### Function

def filterDuplicates (  ( userID, ratings ) ):

```
     (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]

     (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]

     return movie1 < movie2
```

I am getting error due to two continuous parenthesis. Step basically gets an RDD which is basically a list of touple as show below:

```
[(196, ((242, 3.0), (242, 3.0))), (196, ((242, 3.0), (393, 4.0)))]
```

The final result should be only distinct movie ID, rating BY each viewer.

So in the above-given example, 196 is viewer ID, 242 is movie ID and 3.0 is rating given by viewer.

Kindly advise if I need to download a different version of python to use double parenthesis. Presently I have Python 3.7 installed on my machine.

Thanks,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

The variable names inside a tuple is of no use. If you really want the tuple to be parameter of the function, name the whole tuple like

```
def filterDuplicates ( userData ):
     userId = userData[0]
     ratings = userData[1]

     movie1 = ratings[0][0]
     rating1 = ratings[0][1]

     movie2 = ratings[1][0]
     rating2 = ratings[1][1]

     return movie1 < movie2
```